# How can I pass a mysqli result from on php page to another?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I´m executing a mysqli statement in a php file, and I want to pass the results to another php page. I´m storing the result in a session variable, but when I tried to show them in the second php page it appears this error:

> Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_array(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

First php file:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$_SESSION['result'] = $result;
```

Second php page:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = $_SESSION['result']->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        foreach ($row as $r) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="selected" id="selected" checked="checked"></td>
                <td> <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['num'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['num'];
                    }
                    ?></td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>430</td>
                <td>648</td>
                <td>1,055</td>
                <td>-60</td>
                <td>6,448</td>
                <td>7,521</td>
                <td>0,561</td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

I have tried to show the results in the first php page with the same form that I want to show them in the second and it works, but when I do it in the second page it doesn´t work

Comment: You can not send an object (pointer) with the session. You can store the serialized result in the session and can access it.
You can store result in Memcache or Redis instead of session.

Comment: And how can I store the serialized result into session?

Comment: You must, first of all, fetch all of your data and after that store into session

Comment: $_SESSION['result'] = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when the first PHP page finished executing, the output of `get_result` was invalidated as it is just a pointer to a `mysqli::result` object which no longer exists. To work around this you can either save all the results of the query e.g.

```
$_SESSION['results'] = $result->fetch_all();
```

and then in the second file

```
foreach ($_SESSION['results'] as $row)
```

or execute the query again in the second PHP file. You will need to trade off the storage required to save all the results against the time taken to re-execute the query.